# How to call Graph API from MS CRM Javascript? I was trying to adal.js but always getting "User login is required" error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-graph-api

How to call Graph API from MS CRM Javascript? I was trying to adal.js but always getting "User login is required" error
I have configured the AAD aap and provided implicitflow permission too
Please let me know what is missing?

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function CallGraphAPI () {
            "use strict";
            // allowed implicit flow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/get-started-with-office-365-unified-api
            var clientId = "xxxx";

            window.config = {
                subscriptionId: subscriptionId,
                clientId: clientId,
                postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
                endpoints: {
                    graphApiUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
                },
                cacheLocation: 'localStorage' // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
            };
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
            // Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
            var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
            authContext.handleWindowCallback();
            if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
                window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
            }
            // If not logged in force login
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            if (user) {
                // Logged in already
            }
            else {
                // NOTE: you may want to render the page for anonymous users and render
                // a login button which runs the login function upon click.
                authContext.login();
            }
            // Acquire token for Files resource.
            authContext.acquireToken(config.endpoints.graphApiUri, function (error, token) {
                // Handle ADAL Errors.
                if (error || !token) {
                    console.log('ADAL error occurred: ' + error);
                    return;
                }
                // Execute GET request to Files API.
                //var currentUserApiBaseUri = graphApiUri + "/beta/" + config.subscriptionId + "/users/" + user.userName;
                //var filesUri = currentUserApiBaseUri + "/files";
                var filesUri = config.endpoints.graphApiUri + "/beta/me/files";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: filesUri,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    }
                }).done(function (response) {
                    console.log('Successfully fetched files from OneDrive.');
                    console.log(response);
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log('Fetching files from OneDrive failed.');
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="CallGraphAPI()">
    <div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? Would you be able to post your solution?